# Getting started with particles.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, browser, webserver

I'm deploying a simple personal website using [particles.js](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js).

Two questions:

- What is the difference between using particles.min.js and particles.js. There is no documentation regarding this, and from my usage of both, there doesn't seem to be any.
- Is it possible to have a `particles.json` file if I'm running entirely client-side? I am getting errors with it.

Comment: `particles.min.js` is a ***m***inified file of `particles.js`.

Comment: How is that useful @LightningMcQueen ?

Comment: Minifying is all about removing whitespaces, making variable names shorter, etc to improve the performance - see: [Minify JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/en/docs/lighthouse/performance/unminified-javascript/) *Minification is the process of removing whitespace and any code that is not necessary to create a smaller but perfectly valid code file.*

Comment: According to [this codepen](https://codepen.io/VincentGarreau/pen/bGxvQd), you can have your `particles.json` file inside your JavaScript file.

Comment: I know @LightningMcQueen. I'd like to have it separate.

Comment: See: [can't see particles on chrome](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/issues/175#issuecomment-273840175)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a particles.json file entirely on client-side to configure particlejs. make sure that your file is accessible and referenced correctly

Comment: I get an error due to CORS, and I've seen other threads referencing using `file://`, but I want a valid solution instead to use on deployment.